# Passing locals into an $mdDialog when using confirm()

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to show an $mdDialog on a page to confirm deletion of an object. I have a simple delete button on the page, wired to a controller function:

```
<button ng-click="delete(item, $event)">Delete</button>
```

In the controller, I have:

```
$scope.delete = function (item, ev) {
    var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
            .title('Delete item?')
            .textContent('The item will be irretrievably deleted!')
            .ariaLabel('Delete')
            .targetEvent(ev)
            .ok('Delete!')
            .cancel('Cancel');

    $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
        // delete
        console.log("test");
    }, function () {
        // don't delete
    });
};
```

I cannot work out how to pass the `item` object into the actual delete function. The [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) shows how to pass locals into a dialog, but that seems to preclude the use of `confirm()` for building the options.

> **Either** provide an `$mdDialogPreset` returned from `alert()`, and
>   `confirm()`, **or** an options object with the following properties:

(emphasis mine)

Comment: What do you mean by "the actual delete function"? Do you want to set a controller to the dialog and make it delete the item? Or delete the item in the `then`'s callback?

Comment: The easiest way would be ther latter. You can just use `item` in the callback.

Comment: I would like to delete the item in the `then` callback, so just need access to `item` where I have the `//delete` comment.

Comment: Then you don't need to "pass" it. You can just use it there. The callback function is inside the parent function, which is assigned to `$scope.delete`, and can access the parent's argument `item`. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, but I must be :) I thought I'd tried that, but will have another look in the morning. I must've made a mistake.

Comment: Be aware that when set a break point inside the callback that did not already have a reference to the `item` object in the parent function you will not have access to the object. However if you re-run your page after saving the code that does reference the `item` object you will see that it does work. This is the javascript compiler optimisation at work, the compiler needs to know what variables to make available to the callback function before it executes.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use the 'item'.

```
$scope.delete = function (item, ev) {
var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .title('Delete item?')
        .textContent('The item will be irretrievably deleted!')
        .ariaLabel('Delete')
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('Delete!')
        .cancel('Cancel');

$mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function () {
        //item is available here
        console.log(item);
    }, function () {
        // don't delete
    });
};
```